# Custom view instances programmatially added to custom view holder have wrong position and size

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view (extending `View`), a custom view group (extending `LinearLayout`) that's supposed to hold a number of instances of my custom view. Initialisation happens within a `Fragment`.
What I would like to achieve is to have the custom view instances being lined up horizontally in my custom view group (it's supposed to become a multislider in the end). What I have achieved so far: I can add my custom view instances to my custom view group but they're displayed incorrectly - the first instance (a vertical bar) is displayed properly, subsequent bars are neither positioned correctly nor do they have the correct width (see screenshot).

[image: custom view group with]

From querying values like `getX()`, `getWidth()`, `getLeft()`, `getRight()` for my custom view instances I get no hint what's wrong - the values reported indicate that the sliderbars were laid out and positioned properly.

---

There are 3 custom classes involved:

The Fragment

```
public class MultiSliderFragment extends MSBaseFragment {
    private final static String TAG = "MultiSliderFragment";
    private MultiSliderView mMSView;

    public MultiSliderFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View mMSContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multislider_view, container, false);
        mMSView = (MultiSliderView) mMSContainer.findViewById(R.id.multislider_view);
        Bundle numsBundle = this.getArguments();
        ArrayList<Integer> sliderNums = numsBundle.getIntegerArrayList("nums");

        ArrayList<SliderBar> sliders = new ArrayList<>();
        assert sliderNums != null;
        for (int num : sliderNums) {
            SliderBar bar = new SliderBar(getActivity());
            bar.setNum(String.valueOf(num));
            sliders.add(bar);
        }

        int x = 0;
        for (SliderBar slider : sliders) {
            mMSViewLeft.addView(slider);
        }

        // sliders have to know their number
        // and the container view (MultiSliderView)
        // needs  know the dimensions of the screen
        setSliderProps(sliderNums);

        return mMSContainer;
    }

    private void setSliderProps(ArrayList<Integer> sliderNums) {
        MSApplication app = (MSApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
        Point screenDimensions = app.getDimensions();
        mMSView.setScreenDimensions(screenDimensions);
        mMSView.setSliderNums(sliderNums);
    }
}
```

The ViewGroup holding the sliders

```
public class MultiSliderView extends LinearLayout {
    final static private String TAG = "MultiSliderView";
    private ArrayList<Integer> sliderNums;
    private Point screenDimensions;

    public MultiSliderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0);
    }

    public MultiSliderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public MultiSliderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    }

    public void setSliderNums(ArrayList<Integer> sliderNums) {
        this.sliderNums = sliderNums;
    }

    public void setScreenDimensions(Point dimensions) {
        this.screenDimensions = dimensions;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int desiredWidth = getSuggestedMinimumWidth() + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        int desiredHeight = getSuggestedMinimumHeight() + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        int measureWidth = measureDimension(desiredWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int measureHeight = measureDimension(desiredHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth, measureHeight);
    }

    private int measureDimension(int desiredSize, int measureSpec) {
        int result;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            result = desiredSize;
            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }

        if (result < desiredSize) {
            Log.e(TAG, "The view is too small, the content might get cut");
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MultiSliderView on layout: " + left + ", " + top + ", " + right + ", " + bottom);
        int barWidth = getMeasuredWidth()/sliderNums.size();
        int barHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            SliderBar child = (SliderBar) getChildAt(i);
            child.layout(x, 0, x + barWidth, barHeight);
            // increment x by barWidth, otherwise bars are laid out
            // on top of each other, each at position 0 within MultiSliderView
            x += barWidth;
        }
    }

    // manual interaction with the multislider (stub)
    // must report to the regarding SliderBar instance to redraw the slider
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        performClick();
        this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        int tempTouchX = (int) event.getX();
        int tempTouchY = (int) event.getY();

        Log.d(TAG, "touch position: " + tempTouchX + ", " + tempTouchY);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        super.performClick();
        return false;
    }
```

The slider bar

```
public class SliderBar extends View {

    final static String TAG = "SliderBar";
    Paint mPaint;
    Canvas mCanvas;
    String pixelNum;
    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL);
    int left, top, right, bottom;
    Rect mArea = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
    int touchY;

    public SliderBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0);
    }

    public SliderBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public SliderBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.d(TAG, "slider bar on draw: " + left + ", " + top + ", " + right + ", " + bottom);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0x66000000);
        if (touchY <= top) touchY = top;
        if (touchY > bottom) touchY = bottom;
        canvas.drawRect(left, touchY, right, bottom, mPaint);
        mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mPaint.setTypeface(typeFace);
        mPaint.setTextSize((float) 30);
        mPaint.setColor(0xffffffff);
        canvas.drawText(pixelNum, right/2, bottom - 20, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        this.setLeft(left);
        this.setTop(top);
        this.setRight(right);
        this.setBottom(bottom);
        // reports the right values but sliders aren't positioned correctly
        Log.d(TAG, "slider position: " + this.getLeft() + ", " + this.getRight());
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;
        this.right = right;
        this.bottom = bottom;
    }

    public void setNum(String num) {
        this.pixelNum = num;
    }
}
```

Last but not least: The layout containing the MultiSliderView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/multislider_view"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
          android:baselineAligned="false">

<net.myapp.views.MultiSliderView
    android:id="@+id/multislider_view_left"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I thought making `MultiSliderView` inherit from `LinearLayout` would allow me to place my slider bars in a horizontal row, even without giving them a horizontal position. However, that wasn't the case - simply setting their x position to 0 simply positions them on top of each other at position 0.
Is there something obvious I did wrong in positioning the slider bars?

Thanks

Comment: MSBaseFragment is a Fragment subclass that only implements one method `OnFragmentInteractionListener` which is not involved here (just tested - using Fragment instead of MSFragment shows the same result). MSApplication is an Application subclass that basically contains getters and setters to exchange data between various classes. I don't think any of these two are related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get using your code and patching it in some places (getDimension() in the `Application` class will return *widthPixels* and *heightPixels* of current `Window` using `DisplayMetrics`):

[image]

My changes so far:

**1** Sometimes I get a NPE in `onLayout()` of `MultiSliderView` because the `View` is up and running before the numbers `ArrayList` is passed in. So I added a `null` check in `onLayout()` as well as `invalidate();` as the last line in `setSliderNums()`

**2** The `SliderBar`s seem to be positioned nicely (checked using LayoutInspector) but most of the numbers aren't visible. I suppose they should appear in the middle of their `SliderBar` (if I'm wrong, simply skip this point).

Your code to draw the number:

> canvas.drawText(pixelNum, right/2, bottom - 20, mPaint);

This won't work because the values of left, top, etc. are meant relative to the parent `ViewGroup` but you draw on the `Canvas` in coordinates relative to the child `View`. So I changed the line to

```
canvas.drawText(pixelNum, (right - left)/2, bottom - 20, mPaint);
```

**3** Similarly, it seems that `setX()` does not work like you expect it to ("simply setting their x position to 0 simply positions them on top of each other at position 0"), so let me try to explain what it does:

The values used with `setX()` and `setY()` are meant relative to the parent `ViewGroup` containing the `View` in question.
So if you say `view.setX(0);`, the `View` will be drawn at the left edge of its parent `ViewGroup`.

**4** In `onLayout()` of the `SliderBar` it's not necessary to set the *left, top,...* values by calling `this.setLeft(left);` etc. In this method, the `View` is informed about changes which have already been made to these variables. So I skipped the four redundant lines.

**5** What I don't really understand is what you are trying to achieve by the following two lines from `onDraw()` in `SliderBar` :

> if (touchY <= top) touchY = top;
>
> if (touchY > bottom) touchY = bottom;

Basically all they do is set the value of *touchY* to *bottom* if `touchY > bottom` in the beginning (assuming that  `top > bottom`) and leaving *touchY* alone if `touchY <= bottom` in the beginning.

The way things are now, the resulting rectangle is rather one-dimensional in most cases.

So what I'd like to know is what should happen at this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts! I was just trying to put together a minimal example to demonstrate my problem but you were quicker. Anyway, it turned out that the problem lies within `onDraw` in `SliderBar`. I totally didn't consider that positioning on a canvas works differently. Now I have the bars lined up nicely and the numbers are positioned properly. Regarding the ominous `touchY` variable: That shouldn't have been in my example. It's supposed to make sure bars aren't drawn with a negative height or a height that exceeds the available height.

Comment: @5tefan - you're welcome :) About the value of *touchY*: maybe you need an if-else there. But I'm sure you'll make everything work. One question: in what way will the MultiSliderView look different from a horizontal RecyclerView?

Comment: 0X0nosugar - I am fairly new to Android development and didn't know about RecyclerView until now. From what I can see RecyclyerView serves a very different purpose. What I'm trying to achieve is a combination of sliders, but not one where you'd have to set one by clicking and moving a specific slider. Rather you should be able to move you're finger across the sliders and each slider should be set to the position where the finger came across them. This is especially interesting for musical applications. Maybe have a look at this video to see how it should to work: https://youtu.be/mLJNovdGsd0